# using boost condition variable

Tags: c++, boost

i am trying following code to test boost condition variable for synchoronization,
this code does sync. but it shows only 4 values what is wrong here ? , how i can fix it ?

using vs 2012 on windows 7

thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

#include "boost\thread.hpp"
#include "boost\timer.hpp"

using namespace std;

int counter;

boost::mutex m;
boost::condition_variable CworkDone;
bool workdone = true;

bool procOn = true;

void display()
{
while (procOn == true)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);      

    if (workdone)
    {
        cout<<counter<<endl;
        CworkDone.notify_one();
        workdone = false;
    }   
    else 
    {
        CworkDone.wait(lock);
    }
}

}

void increment()
{
for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ; ++i)
{

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);

    if (!workdone)
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
        ++counter;
        workdone = true;
        CworkDone.notify_one();
    }
    else
    {
        CworkDone.wait(lock);
    }
}
procOn = false;
}

   int main()
{
boost::thread dispthread(display);
boost::thread incthread(increment);
dispthread.join();
incthread.join();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is a class producer/consumer problem. Your code as it stands doesn't really make sense - you cannot use a single condition variable for waiting on both sides, (remember you call notify then wait - on the same condition, in the same context.) So anything can happen.

You need to refactor your code to use two condition variables, one for the producer, one for the consumer, for example:

EDIT: Updated with a pure c++11 implementation which should be correct.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

mutex mutex_;
condition_variable con_, prd_;
atomic_bool done_{false}, process_{false}; // possibly overkill, but hey-ho
int counter = 0; // protected resource

void consumer()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex_);       // acquire the mutex before waiting
    // this is the correct way to wait on the condition (as highlighted by @Dale)
    con_.wait(lock, []{ return process_.load() || done_.load(); });
    if (!done_.load())
    {
      cout << counter << endl;
      process_.store(false);               // we're done with this item
      lock.unlock();                       // release before notifying
      prd_.notify_one();
    }
    else
      break;                               // we're done completely
  }
}

void producer()
{
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex_);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    ++counter;
    process_.store(true);                 // indicate that there is data
    con_.notify_one();
    // wait for the consumer to complete
    prd_.wait(lock, []{ return !process_.load(); });
  }
  done_.store(true);                      // we're done
  lock.unlock();                          // release before notifying
  con_.notify_one();
}

int main(void)
{
  thread c(consumer);
  producer();
  c.join();
}
```

So now what happens is, the consumer waits on it's condition (and only the producer will call `notify()` on this), and the producer, once it has produced something calls this notify which will wake the client up. The client will then call `notify()` to wake the producer up.

The above updated approach should not suffer the spurious wake up problem as I highlighted before. This negates the need for a `timed_wait`.

Comment: there is dedelock somehow code simply hangs after printing some values , however if i debug step by step things work fine.

Comment: thanks, i am trying two variable. it works but sometimes code hangs seems some sort of race condition or dead lock, i am also trying wait on time but no luck yet.

Comment: @vivek - the above still hangs? Really - it works fine for me (though I'm using GCC on linux.) The `timed_wait()` approach really only works if you have a queue between the producer and consumer...I'm surprised you are hitting issues with the simple example above..

Comment: well i use time wait and it resolve issue for me. i don't have linux. any way thanks using two condition variable works well.

Comment: Forget the time_wait.  The code that uses the condition variable is wrong.  The reason it is failing is you need to check the procOn value AFTER locking the mutex and BEFORE waiting on the condition variable -- otherwise you will get intermittent hangs (which are hidden by the timed-wait).

Comment: @Nim  As I mentioned in a previous comment and as vivek discovered, your answer has a serious problem.  The code as presented in the answer has a race condition that will cause a hang. Please edit the code in your question to use a timed wait, or better yet to handle the condition variable in accordance with the common (and correct!) idiom mentioned in my answer.   As it stands, this answer will mislead anyone who doesn't read the comments carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Nim was right about needing separate producer and consumer condition_variables, but the original code in that answer for waiting for the condition was flawed [see note below]  which is why vivek needed to used timed_wait (not a desirable solution, BTW).

Nim has since repaired the code so If you are using C++11 the code in Nim's answer is a good solution.

If you are stuck on older versions of C++, the code below will work.

The common idiom for using a condition_variable is:

```
lock the mutex
while (not ready to go)
    condition_variable.wait()
do it
```

And, yes, false positives are possible which is why the above code retests "ready to go" after returning from the condition_variable.wait() call.

The boost::wait method overloaded with a function object (in this case a lambda function) that Nim uses implements this idiom and including ignoring false positives (which still happens).  It does this using the function object to test the "ready-to-go" condition, and does not return until it has re-acquired the lock and re-tested the function.

The code below works pre-C++ 11 and without using the function object-based boost wait making it clear what actually happens.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex m;
boost::condition_variable cProducer;
boost::condition_variable cConsumer;
volatile bool readyToDisplay = false;
volatile bool done = false;

void display()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
    while(!done)
    {
        while (!readyToDisplay)
        {
           cConsumer.wait(lock);
        }
        cout << counter << endl;
        readyToDisplay = false;
        cProducer.notify_one();
    }
}

void increment()
{
  while(!done)
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
    while(readyToDisplay)
    {
       cProducer.wait(lock);
    }
    ++counter;
    readyToDisplay = true;
    done = (counter == 10);
    cConsumer.notify_one();
  }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread dispthread(display);
    boost::thread incthread(increment);
    dispthread.join();
    incthread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

Note:  To help others navigate this thorny area (and see what the fuss was about) the original answer contained code similar to this in the display method: (line #'s added, and some details omitted.)

```
1: while (!done)
2: {
3:   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
4:   cConsumer.wait(lock);
5:   std::cout << counter << endl;
6:   cProducer.notify_one();
7: }
```

Suppose that right before this thread executes line 3 the other thread increments the counter and calls notify_one on the condition variable.  When this thread locks the mutex on line 3 and waits on line 4 the notification that should make it wake up has already happened so the wait will hang forever.

Answer (score 0):

The program shows 5 values not 4

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Your loop

```
void increment()
{
for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ; ++i)
```

notifies only 5 times of the 10 as the notification is done only here

```
if (!workdone)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
    ++counter;
    workdone = true;
    CworkDone.notify_one();
}
```

and this condition is true one over two.

To fix it, all depends on what do you want to do. If you want to be notified 10 times change the counter from 10 to 20 ;-)

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried this but loop does not exit.any way i need to do process 10 times. and display 10 values.

Answer (score -1):

just add boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(10) before 
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
in increment function.
A little bit syncronization issue

Comment: I would have up-voted this answer if I thought you had a really dry sense of humor, but part of me thinks you are serious.